# Mac Touchbar App - Add Shortcut to bring touch bar to front

Tags: swift, nstouchbar

i am currently developing a Mac TouchBar application.
Now I want to add a shortcut to this application so that I can bring the touch bar into front when another application is active. The TouchBar application TouchSwitcher have this feature.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The suggested app doesn't do what you claim it does https://hazeover.com/touchswitcher.html